# Chromium Crashes while Video Conferencing

Tags: qt, chromium, qtwebengine

I am building an application using Qt and QWebEngine which uses chromium back end. After one or two minutes in the conference (Only I am in the room and sharing my camera feed) the whole web engine freezes and I get no response. It prints these messages in the console:

```
[4760:4777:0105/080543.432601:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
[4760:4777:0105/080543.500689:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
[4760:4777:0105/080543.520016:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
[4722:4748:0105/080546.062242:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(249)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.2sAJUM failed: Too many open files (24)
[4762:10:0100/000000.068025:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
[4722:4739:0105/080546.068751:ERROR:unix_domain_socket.cc(194)] recvmsg returned MSG_CTRUNC flag, buffer len is 0
[4722:4748:0105/080546.070291:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(249)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.4tUFk2 failed: Too many open files (24)
[4722:4739:0105/080546.070768:ERROR:unix_domain_socket.cc(194)] recvmsg returned MSG_CTRUNC flag, buffer len is 0
[4762:10:0100/000000.070574:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
[4722:4748:0105/080546.070969:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(249)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.0JRpo8 failed: Too many open files (24)
[4722:4739:0105/080546.071154:ERROR:unix_domain_socket.cc(194)] recvmsg returned MSG_CTRUNC flag, buffer len is 0
[4762:9:0100/000000.071083:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
[4722:4739:0105/080546.149295:ERROR:unix_domain_socket.cc(194)] recvmsg returned MSG_CTRUNC flag, buffer len is 0
[4762:4:0100/000000.149163:ERROR:validation_errors.cc(76)] Invalid message: VALIDATION_ERROR_UNEXPECTED_INVALID_HANDLE (invalid field 1)
```

My application opens only one tab and I have checked and there is 4 GB `/dev/shm`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        59G  9.9G   46G  18% /
devtmpfs        3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G   23M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  8.6M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   54M  199M  22% /boot
tmpfs           783M  4.0K  783M   1% /run/user/1000
```

and also `ulimit -a` returns:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 60532
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 95
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 60532
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I have increased open files to 4000 and didn't help.
I have no Idea what is causing that. My hardware is Raspberry Pi 4B 8G RAM.

Comment: looks like it's a bug in Chromium. You can talk with other Chromium developers about this issue here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev or file a bug here: https://crbug.com

Comment: I appreciate your response. Its is a bug but not in chromium. I have reviewed the code in different commits and the `unix_domain_socket.cc(194)` it mentions in debug outputs, looks like this: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/master/base/posix/unix_domain_socket.cc#90 or this: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/base/posix/unix_domain_socket.cc#192 nothing significant changed there. See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is a bug but I don't know where exactly. I'm sure that Qt is responsible for that. I have cross compiled Qt 5.13.0 and the issue is not showing up. My first build was with Qt5.15.2 which was freezing. Also I have logged in the Skype with chromium web browser on raspberry pi and the issue didn't show up. That was when I figured something must be wrong with Qt's Web Engine.
Also I had some issues with 5.13.0 on raspberry, I couldn't run the app with eglfs platform instead I'm using linuxfb.

Comment: Just to clarify, in contrast to a comment elsewhere on this (your answer post) I do consider this a contribution to the answer-finding process on this question. This is independent whether  the author of this post is identical to the author of the question or not. This can be seen as a "partial answer", i.e. contributing to the answer-finding even if not fully solving. Posting like this is appreciated as long as a full solution does not exist, or is doubted. (And I would not expect you to take it down when a solution arrives, in my opinion you stay entitled to the reward from  upvotes then.)